# Return the value from a class within a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the html I'm working with

```
<table class="forum_unread" id="post1093990">
    <td class="body">
        <div id="content1093990" class="postcontent">
            899,906
        </div>
   </td>
</table>
```

I'm trying to get the value 899,906 from the code above using jQuery

```
var a = $('.forum_unread').siblings('.body')
                          .children('.postcontent')
                          .last()
                          .text();

console.log(a);
```

The console returns undefined for some reason

Comment: `.body` is not `sibling` of `.forum_unread`. It's `children`.

Comment: Every step you chain with `.` returns a value by itself. Try to store each step in a variable. It would probably be clear then...

Comment: @Tushar — It isn't actually a child, it just looks that way because the tbody and tr elements are missing from the HTML.

Comment: try $("#content1093990").text()

Comment: Use `$(.forum_unread .postcontent').text()`

Comment: @Yuri — You are confusing children and descendants. I am not my grandfather's child.

Comment: Please don't downvote questions just because you think they are too simple. The OP properly explained the problem and what went wrong

Comment: @Quentin you are right, I confused the two :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.body` is not sibling of `.forum_unread`

Try this:

```
var a = $(".forum_unread .postcontent").text();
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Because the id is a variable that changes in every post. I'm trying to work with constants.